# how to use a variable in another part of the code?

Tags: cocoa-touch

```
`- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSInteger *pushUpCount;
 }

`- (IBAction)imPressed:(id)sender {
   NSInteger pushUpCount = pushUpCount + 1;
   NSString *strPushUp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pushUpCount];
   NSLog(strPushUp);
   }
```

No my problem is that it says that the `pushUpCount` is not declared. So I was wondering how could I make this "`public`", so that all of the of the functions or `IBActions` can use this variable. I know what the problem is I don't know how to fix it.

---

CODE EXPLANATION
All I'm doing here is setting the variable to 0. Before the user does anything. Then each time the button is pressed it will add 1 to the existing number. then I will change the text of a `NSTextField` to the number but I  know how to do that.(or I think I do at least).

So my basic question is..... How can I reuse a variable in another function or `IBAction`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make this variable a member of your class. I.e. declare it inside `@interface` section and assign it 0 inside `viewDidLoad` just like this: `pushUpCount = 0;`
2. Don't use it as a pointer (i'm pretty sure it's not what you need). Declare it `NSInteger pushUpCount;` instead of `NSInteger *pushUpCount;`
3. Inside `imPressed` just increment it `pushUpCount++;`

In order to make sure you understand everything i'll explain it very simple:

Your `@interface` section in `YourViewController.h` file should contain declaration of the variable:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSInteger pushUpCount;
}
@end
```

Now your code looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  pushUpCount = 0;
}

 - (IBAction)imPressed:(id)sender {
pushUpCount++;
NSString *strPushUp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pushUpCount];
NSLog(strPushUp);
 }
```

Comment: I don't really under stand what you mean but I changed It and I get the pointer(at least I think its the pointer of the variable) printed out in the NSLOG. I have updated my question could you explain it more.

Comment: What exactly you can't get?

Comment: never mind you updated your answer and it helped me a lot. I get what you did thank you.